# MySQL replication with custom query for reverse hashes

Tags: mysql, replication, union, lookup, sha1

I have a MySQL DB with a quickly growing amount of data.

I'd like to use some web based tool that plugs into the DB so that I can analyze data and create reports.

The idea would be to use replication in order to give R/O access to the slave DB instead of having to worry about security issues on the master (which also contains data not relevant to this project, but just as important).

The master DB contains strings that are hashed (SHA1 128) from the source and, on the slave, they need to go back to their original form using a reverse hash database.

This will allow whatever tool I plug into the slave-DB (living on another server) to work straight out of the box.

My question is: what is the best way to do replication while somehow reshaping the slave-DB with the mentioned strings back into the source format?

**example**

```
MASTER DB
a8866ghfde332as
a8fwe43kf3e3t42

SLAVE DB
John Smith
Rose White
```

The slave DB should already contain the tables reversed and should NOT be reversed when doing a query.

How do you guys think I should approach this? 
Is replication the way to go?

Thank you for any help!

**EDIT**

I should specify some details:

- the slave DB would also contain a reverse hash (lookup) table
- the amount of source strings is limited so there's little risk of collisions
- the best option would be to replicate only certain tables to the slave, where the slave-DB does a reverse hash lookup every time there is an INSERT and saves the reversed hash in another table (or column) ready to be read by the web based tool

This type of setup I am willing to use is mainly focused on NOT having anything connecting to the master other than the source (that creates records in the DB) and the slave DB itself.

This would result in better security by having the reverse lookup table sitting in a DB (the slave) that is NOT in direct contact with the source of data.

So, even in case somebody hacks the source and makes it to the master DB, no useful data could be retrieved being the strings in object hashed.

Comment: Hash values are not unique, so you can only ever retrieve *one of the possible values*.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a slave instance contains the same data as its master. You may be wanting a snapshot or replica of some, but not all tables, in your data base.  (By the way, if this is health data in the US, check with your security officer before proceeding on this project.)

Comment: Reversing a hash function is VERY expensive. It's intended to be almost impossible.

Comment: @Barmar, the OP said he had a lookup table for this purpose. Presumably he doesn't mean a cracker's rainbow table, but a table populated at the same time as his other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier, simpler, and most foolproof to replicate *everything* from master to slave in MySQL, so plan to relicate everything unless you have an extremely compelling reason not to.

That said, MySQL has absolutely no problem with the slave having tables that the master does not have -- tables created directly on the slave will not cause a problem if no tables with conflicting schema+table names exist on the master.

You don't want to try to have the slave "fix" the data on the way in, because that's not something MySQL replication is designed to do, nor is it something readily accomploahed.  Triggers will fire on tables on the slave *only* when the master writes events to its binlog in statement mode, which is not as reliable as row mode nor as flexible as mixed mode, and even if you had this working, you then lose the ability to compare master and slave data sets with table checksums, which is an important part of the ongoing maintenance of master/slave replication.

However... I do see a way to accomplish what you want to do with the reverse hash tables: create the lookup tables on the slave, and then create views that reconstruct the data in its desired form by joining the replicated tables to the lookup tables, and run your queries on the slave against these views.

When a view simply joins properly indexed tables and doesn't include anything unusual like aggregate functions (e.g. `COUNT()`) or `UNION` or `EXISTS`, then, the server will process queries against views as if the underlying tables had been queried directly, using all available and appropriate indexes... so this approach should not cause significant performance penalties.  In fact, you can declare indexes on replicated tables on the slave (on replicated tables) that you don't have or need on the master (except for `UNIQUE` indexes, which wouldn't make sense) and these can be designed as needed for the slave-specific workload.

Answer (score 0):

Hash functions are [surjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective), so it is possible for two different inputs to have the same output. As such, it would not be possible to *accurately* rebuild the data on the slave.

On a simple level,  and to demonstrate this; consider a hashing function for integers, that happens to return the square of the input; so, -1 => 1, 0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 4, 3 => 9, etc. Now consider the inverse, being the square root, 1 => -1 & 1, 4 => -2 & 2, etc.

It may be better to only replicate the specific data needed for your project to the slaves, and do it without hashing.